# Redirect output and error to the same file using ProcessExecutor

Tags: java, shell, logging, queue

I am using ProcessExecutor org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor, for executing a shell script in Java. The requirement is to to color code any error logs from the execution and write the output from both streams out and err to the same file.

Currently, I am initializing this as

```
  ProcessExecutor processExecutor = new ProcessExecutor()
                                        .command(commandList)
                                        .directory(dir)
                                        .environment(environment)
                                        .readOutput(true)
                                        .stopper(..)
                                        .redirectOutput(new LogOutputStream() {
                                          //print
                                        })
                                        .redirectError(new LogOutputStream() {
                                          //color code to red and print
                                        })
```

The issue is that sometimes the order of the logs is incorrect since they are 2 different streams and there is no coordination between them.

I am okay moving away from ProcessExecutor as well.

Thanks!